# In Unity 2021.2, using UI Toolkit features, how do I effect click-and-hold to a child Button of a list-item in a ListView?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to Unity and I'm trying to build an in-game reorderable list using the UI Toolkit features.

I'm populating a ListView element with a Visual Tree Asset that is a composite of several Label and Button elements.

I would like to be able to click-and-hold a button (perhaps on the left-side) in the list-item and then drag the list-item, up or down, to the position I want in the list.

[image]

I was able to successfully bind the clickable.clicked function to a list-item child Button using the following code:

```
Action<VisualElement, int> bindItem = (e, i) => {
    var reorder_button = e.Q<Button>("reorder_button");
    if (reorder_button != null) reorder_button.clickable.clicked += () => ReorderClicked(e);
};
```

where the function called is:

```
void ReorderClicked(VisualElement ve)
{
    var title = ve.Q<Label>("title");
    Debug.Log("Clicked " + title.text);
};
```

This works as expected but how would I expand on this to accommodate click-and-hold or a mouse-down / mouse-up event?

It was suggested that I use the features in Unity for dragging events but I don't see a way of implementing this in the UI Toolkit framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Unity, but found a couple of solutions to this. It looks like you can add custom drag handlers by inheriting the `PointerManipulator` or `MouseManipulator` classes (see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-create-drag-and-drop-ui.html) for example that almost works as-is):

```
Action<VisualElement, int> bindItem = (e, i) =>
{
    ...
    e.AddManipulator(new DragAndDropManipulator(e));
}
```

You'd have to alter the implementation of `PointerCaptureOutHandler` from slot based to list ordering.

**However**, it appears that this behaviour is built into Unity (at least in my version - 2021.3.12f1). `ListView` has a [`reorderable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.ListView-reorderable.html) property that you can set to `true` to enable drag and drop reordering. You can add drag animations by setting [reorderMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.ListView-reorderMode.html) to `Animated`.

Original source from [unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/runtime-reordering-list-view-visually.1252416/).